# is there anyway where I can get the values inside the memo object without running into undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to print the values inside the memo object, but I am getting undefined while is clear that there is values inside the memo object, or even iterating the object to get the values, please help.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function iter(arr, n, memo = {}) {
  if (n < arr.length) {
    memo[n] = iter(arr, n + 1);
  }

  // iterate memo object and print the values
  // memo = { '0': { '1': { '2': [Object] } } }
  for (let i in memo) {
    console.log(memo[i]);
    // I am getting undefined
  }
  // also here when I return the first value I am gettng undefined
  //
  return memo["0"];
}

console.log(iter(arr, 0));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to print the values that the recursion stored in the memo object.

Comment: You aren't passing your memo object to recursive calls, so `memo` is always an empty object as declared by the default, and won't have a `0` property unless called with and `n` of 0.

Comment: That's true, that's what I am missing thank you.

Comment: plichard I am still getting undefined, do you mind rephrasing my code

Comment: Is that output you expect from `[1, 2, 3, 4]` really `{ '0': { '1': { '2': [Object] } } }`, or did you perhaps want `{ '1': { '2': [Object] } }` instead for that input? (What exactly determines the keys for the object?)

Comment: Yes the second one, I am freaking confused.

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
if(n < arr.length){
   memo[n] = iter(arr,n+1)
}
```

and

```
return memo['0']
```

at the bottom of the function, this means that:

- You don't pass `memo` along in the recursive call, so you're creating a new object each time `iter` runs. Even if you fix that -
- You return `memo['0']` - but that 0 index is only assigned to at the very end of all the recursive calls. (`n` starts at 0, you enter recursion, then you eventually exit recursion, and finally at that point do you assign to `memo[0]` - not before - so before then, it's always `undefined`.)

If what you wanted was

```
memo = { '1': { '2': [Object] } }
```

then `.reduceRight` would be more appropriate to produce that structure. (`memo` isn't a good name because you aren't memoizing anything). The `n` variable doesn't look to be accomplishing anything here that `.reduceRight` can't handle by itself easier.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
function iter(arr, n) {
  return arr.reduceRight((prevValue, prop) => ({ [prop]: prevValue }));
}
console.log(iter(arr, 0))
```

If you wanted to use explicit recursion here, then perhaps something like

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function iter(arr, n) {
  return n === arr.length - 1
    ? arr[n]
    : { [arr[n]]: iter(arr, n + 1) };
}

console.log(iter(arr, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];


function iter(arr, n, memo = {}) {
  if (n < arr.length) {
    memo[n] = iter(arr, n + 1, memo) +
      iter(arr, n + 1, memo)
  }

  for (let i in memo) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}


console.log(iter(arr, 0))
```